# Runtime error 9 on Array Copy

Tags: vba, excel

Receiving Run-time error'9': Subscript out of range

I am trying to save a copy of all sheets (or essentially copy the entire workbook) as a new workbook (.xlsx file type) with today's date.

Code:

```
Sub Test()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

spPath = "C:\Users\mchun\Documents\Reporting Projects\Report Automation\Pop Counts (Monthly Field Population Reports EXCEL)\"
spFileName = "AandR Field Counts_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (spPath & spFileName)

ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Sheets(Array("Assignment Counts", "Assignment Percentages", "Release Counts", "Release Percentages")).Copy _
Workbooks.Add(spPath & spFileName)


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (spPath & spFileName)

ActiveWorkbook.CheckIn

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Debug highlights this:

```
Sheets(Array("Assignment Counts", "Assignment Precentages", "Release Counts", "Release Percentages")).Copy _
Workbooks.Add(spPath & spFileName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: let's try something different. Replace the appropriate section of your code with this fragment

```
spFileName = "AandR Field Counts_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"

ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Sheets(Array("Assignment Counts", "Assignment Percentages", "Release Counts", "Release Percentages")).Copy

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (spPath & spFileName)
```

Using [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835605(v=office.15).aspx) without a destination creates a new workbook containing the selected sheets. Once that happens we just save the workbook with the appropriate name and path

(The original version didn't work because you need to specify a worksheet and not a workbook. Putting `Workbooks(spFileName).Worksheets(1)` in the `Copy` command in the original code should also work)

---

original post:

You have `Workbooks.Add(spPath & spFileName)` in the `Sheets(...).Copy` command. You already have an open workbook with the name referred to by spFileName (created earlier in the macro).

Either choose a different name if you want to create a second workbook or just use `Workbooks(spFileName)` to refer to the workbook you have already created. You can't have two workbooks open simultaneously with the same name in the same instance of Excel

Comment: I need these to be copied to this workbook so I can't use a different name. Would you recommend that I just remove the initial workbook creation and save?

I tried this and am now receiving an error - "Run-time error '1004': Sorry we couldn't find [spPath and spFileName values]. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

Comment: Just change: `Sheets(Array("Assignment Counts", "Assignment Percentages", "Release Counts", "Release Percentages")).Copy _
Workbooks.Add(spPath & spFileName)` to `Sheets(Array("Assignment Counts", "Assignment Percentages", "Release Counts", "Release Percentages")).Copy _
Workbooks(spFileName)` (i.e. lose the `.Add` after Workbooks and take out the path)

Comment: Received error "Run-time error '1004': Copy method of Sheets class failed"

Debugger is pointing to this same line.

Comment: Looks to be working now, thank you!

I actually had something very similar (if not identical) to this in another Macro but, for whatever reason, it wasn't working and was throwing errors.